# multiple div with same template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a '`users page`'. I would like to give a `textbox` for entering the no. of users. On click of `submit` '`n`' no of user forms need to be presented to user.

```
User1

first name - 

last name -

User2

first name -

last name -

.
.
.

UserN

first name - 

last name -
```

I don't know the value of '`N`' upfront. So it won't be a good idea to write multiple 'divs' in my html.

**Requirement**:Rather I want to have a user template div. And copy the template '`n`' times depending on the value of '`n`' in the `textbox`. But I would also want all the '`divs`' to have different ids like `'user1', 'user2'` etc.

I cannot figure out a way to do this apart from populating my html with too many '`divs`'. Would need help achiving the Requirement specified.

Looking for a template like:-

```
<div id="user-template" class="hidden">
      <label class="lbl"><b>Handle:</b></label><input type="text" id="first_name" value=""/>
</div>
```

And wanted to have id="`user-template`" change for all new divs.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Thats what I said, I am using multiple forms right now. DOWNVOTED-damn...I am new to HTML, JS and the problem seems out of box with the knowledge I have so far. Just wanted a direction.

Comment: You should get into HTML, JavaScript and JQuery for a beginner i think its  something very broad once you learn enough JavaScript and JQuery it should be fairly easy.

Comment: Thanks...fair enough....will do that!! But any directions for now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JavaUIDeveloper/fq545x3b/):

You can make a template and append it to the DOM for the number entered in the input field.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#createForms").click(function() {
    var numOfForms = $("#numOfForms").val();
    var template = $('#hidden-template').html();
    for (var i = 0; i < numOfForms; i++) {
      $('#targetDiv').append("<p>User" + (i + 1) + ":</p>");
      $('#targetDiv').append(template);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="numOfForms"></input>
<input type="button" id="createForms" value="Get Fields"></input>

<div id="targetDiv"></div>


<script id="hidden-template" type="text/x-custom-template">
  <div id="user-template" class="hidden">
    <p>First Name:
      <input type="text" name="firstName"></input>
    </p>
    <p>Last Name:
      <input type="text" name="lastName"></input>
    </p>
    <br>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks!! exactly what I wanted. I know it was easy but I was directionless. Thanku so much.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to write a function that takes the n value and returns the actual dom that you can append to some parent element on your page. A simple example below:

```
function createNDivs(n) {
  if(!n) return;

  var fragment =document.createDocumentFragment();
  for(var i=0;i<n;i++) {
       var div = document.createElement('div');
       fragment.appendChild(div);
   }

   return fragment;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget you will need to append the fragment to the parent element with .appendChild(createNDivs(n));

Comment: htm5 also have a template attribute but has limited browser support as of now , this might be a good read if interested [html template](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/)